# Insect species identification

Tags: species-identification, entomology, lepidoptera

[image: Does anyone know what this insect is?]

I think it's a moth and need further identification like scientific name, order and family.

The picture was taken on May 30/2016 in my university laboratory window in South Korea. At that time there were so many moths on this building. The temperature was also high and it was also daytime around lunch time. What I want to ask related to flying time is do moths fly at daytime? as far as I know moths are nocturnal. Please clarify this too if this insect species is moth.

Comment: Hi, maybe you'll find these hints helpful in improving your question: http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask. `Temperature was high`... high for where? Also `do moths fly in the daytime` is a seperate question, as is `are all moths nocturnal`.

Comment: @ Troyseph what is wrong with my question,Sir?

Comment: It was poorly formatted such that the picture wasn't visible and you had a block of text with random '[' characters in it. You ask multiple questions. You show no attempt at your own research into its type. You gave details which are completely useless to us, i.e. the temperature was **high**... did your building have the heating on? Do you live in Florida or Iceland? is high 24 degrees C or 34 degrees c? Please put some effort into your question so that someone might put effort into an answer for you =]

Comment: @ Troyseph I think it's better to focus on answering the question rather than editing the grammar since there is n o misunderstanding. lol If it's useless and do not know the answer just stop criticizing period

Comment: I wasn't criticising your grammar, spelling or punctuation. Please read the guidelines and take my advice, then your question will be clearer and easier to answer.

Comment: @Meti please [edit] your question and post where *exactly* the picture was taken. *`in my university laboratory window`* is not helpful at all. I would also strongly suggest you take the [tour] and read carefully through the [help] to learn more about the site. Editing of questions (and answers) is encouraged, subject to some guidelines. You should also read [this Meta.SE question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7931), especially the section Editing and Formatting.

Comment: Am very sorry @ Troyseph I didn't know that. @MattDMo I will take all your suggestions and advice into consideration.

Answer (score 3):

It is a moth and all moths and butterflies belong to the order of *Lepidoptera*. Based on the shape of the forewing and the orange color of the hindwings I think this moth belongs to the genus *Catocala* https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catocala, see also [here](http://www.acmaeodera.cz/acmaeodera/46-OTHER-INSECT/297-CATOCALA-GALLERY) for some pictures.

EDIT:
theforestecologist did a excellent suggestion that this might be [*Catocala streckeri*](http://www.jpmoth.org/~dmoth/Korea0606/80_Noctuidae/Catocala%20streckeri/Catocala_streckeri_060624303.jpg) based on the wing pattern. This species does occur in Korea, see [this](http://www.nic.funet.fi/pub/sci/bio/life/insecta/lepidoptera/ditrysia/noctuoidea/noctuidae/catocalinae/catocala/index.html) website for a distribution map. So it may indeed be *Catocala streckeri*. However, Asia is very rich in Catacola species, and I know that this family often has species looking very alike, so I can't say with 100% certainty.

Most, but not all, moths are nocturnal. Some *Catocala* species are known to fly on sunny afternoons (Waring&Townsend 2006).

Comment: thank you for your response. The picture was taken in South Korea.

Comment: [*Catocala streckeri*](http://www.jpmoth.org/~dmoth/Korea0606/80_Noctuidae/Catocala%20streckeri/Catocala_streckeri_060624303.jpg) seems like a pretty good guess given the wing pattern. I'd add it as my own answer, but obviously cannot because the question is closed.

Comment: @theforestecologist: excellent find. I'll add it to my answer.